# How are Win32 types represented in C# P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I am trying to call the PrintDlgW Win32 API from C# via P/Invoke. With the help of [P/Invoke Interop Assistant 1.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/06/23/p-invoke-interop-assistant-justin-van-patten.aspx) from Microsoft, I am able to declare necessary data structures and import functions from DLL. But how to use the HDC or HWND in C#? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/comdlg32/PRINTDLG.html) has nice examples with structures already defined for quite a few APIs.  The structure is [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/PRINTDLG.html).

Answer (score 4):

HWND in C++ is really a void *, which is represented in C# by the IntPtr type.

Answer (score 1):

It might make it easier to do this

```
using HWND = System.IntPtr;
```

Then use HWND in your pInvoke...to make it easier to read and keep it "the same" as the pinvoke signature.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: You can do this if you like your C# to look like C++.  Personally, I would avoid that.